# Languages with graph data structures and algorithms in standard library

Tags: graph, graph-traversal, standard-library

I am trying to improve my knowledge and ability with graphs and graph algorithms and have noticed something curious: as far as I can tell no "mainstream" language contains support for graphs in its standard library. Trees yes, graphs no. The only language that comes even remotely close is C++ with Boost (which isn't technically a "standard library")

I'm not sure exactly why this is, but it's got me wondering: are there any programming languages out there that come with solid support for graphs as part of their standard library?

Edit: To clarify: by "graph" I mean a network of nodes and edges; the sort of thing you'd run Dijkstra's algorithm on, not a "graph" in the sense of "graphical display of data".

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why that is, but I would guess that part of it may be that it would be very difficult to agree on what to put in such a library, and implementing it would probably be more difficult than a standard string manipulation library. Also, I found this: http://www.cs.york.ac.uk/plasma/wiki/index.php?title=GP_(Graph_Programs) It's not all that mainstream, but it does look like a programming language designed for working with graphs, with built-in graph operations and support.

Comment: ...Also, it might be that there simply hasn't been enough of a demand for languages to have built-in graph support, and when people *do* need it, they either build their own library or choose one from several pre-existing ones (such as the Boost library).

Comment: It all depends on your definition of "mainstream" language.  [Maple](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~carl/ma322/html/intro2.html) *is* a graphing language, for instance.  Perhaps that's mainstream, but is that because it isn't widely used or because you can't use it for non-graphing purposes?

Comment: @Neil: the link you posted mentions Lists, Sets, Trees and Tables, but no Graphs. Are you sure that the Maple standard library includes a Graph data structure?

Comment: related: [What should and shouldn't be included in a standard library?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/51951/31260)

Comment: @JörgWMittag Scroll down and you see things like `plot(x^2+x, x=-3..3); # plots x^2+x as x goes from -3 to 3`.

Comment: *graph* has at least two different meanings that could apply here. Do you mean *graph data structure* as in *object graph*, a network of interconnected objects? Or do you mean *graph data structure* as in a data structure for plotting line graphs and such? The former seems like something that you might want in a standard library, except that its hard to see how you'd do that in a generic but still useful way that's different from, say, a map. The latter would be expected in the standard library of a language focused on numerical analysis, like R, but not in something more general, like C.

Comment: I don't remember the last time I've wanted a graph library. Typically, if the graph is pretty dense, I use a matrix, but if it's sparse, I use a map. These are two **very** different data structures, so it would be hard to make a unified solution that is also performant, which is what a standard lib would need. Since it's so dependent on use-case, I'd have to point to @gnat's link.

Comment: @Caleb I meant the former, thank you for pointing that out. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @Neil I'm sorry I didn't originally clarify in the question, I meant graph as in the data structure of nodes and edges. Also, by mainstream I did an (admittedly cursory) research of the top 10 or so languages on Tiobe and couldn't find support for graphs in the standard library of any of them.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Thank you for that link. Definitely not mainstream but that actually looks extremely interesting.

Answer (score 4):

One way of looking at this is that any time you have a data structure that references another data structure, you have some form of object graph.  On that level, any object-oriented language supports a graph.  Some languages are not object oriented and instead use a map to store related data structures.  This also creates graphs of related maps, so any language with an associative array (PHP) or hashMap (Clojure, perl, etc) can make graphs with maps.

But I think you are asking why there aren't more tookits that have something like

```
Node {
    Iterator<Node> getAdjacentNodes();
}

Graph {
    void putNode(Node n);
    Iterator<Node> getAllNodes();
}
```

Look at Datomic.  Also triple-stores use something like this.  Similarly, cross-reference (xref) tables in relational databases can be used to create arbitrary graphs of relationships.

Having said that, I might restate your question as "Why don't more programming languages and tool-kits take a graph-based approach to problem decomposition?"

I think the answer is that efficient generic graph traversal is an NP-Hard problem lacking both a universal, efficient way to process graphs, and also a universal, efficient way to prove that a single solution is the most efficient one (e.g. the Travelling Salesman problem).

Graphs are absolutely essential for every CS student to learn because they deal with the most general relationships between data.  Yet for that same reason, they should be your last choice for how to represent relationships.  Most relationships are more specific.  A car should only have one driver and one position on a given road at a time.  There is generally no reason to join all cars with all possible drivers and all possible roads.  Doing so would invite unnecessarily difficult problems.  The more specific you can make the relationships between your objects or functions in your program design, the more you can optimize those relationships and the easier it is to understand and test them.

Finally, how do you traverse graphs?  There is depth-first and breadth-first.  Most programming languages make breadth-first traversal easy:

```
select * from passenger where car_id = 3;

myCar.getCurrentPassengers();
```

When you look at depth-first search, there is no one right way to do it.  What's the best road from New York to San Francisco?  It's solvable, but only by a fairly brute-force approach.  If intersections are nodes and roads are edges, that doesn't help you solve this problem.  Far better is it to know something about the roads - which ones are interstates, have traffic lights or stop-signs, are under construction, are prone to traffic, are closed, or not built yet?  Your NYC to San Fran route search might start with just interstates, then examine the angles of intersection where you change roads, or the maximum distance from a straight (well, curved around the globe) line.  These are footholds to finding an optimal solution efficiently.  They hint at places to check for more local roads that work around a less-than-ideal interstate solution.  The details of the problem are exactly what makes real-time, real-world route finding possible.  Yet the details are precisely the aspect of graph traversal that a generic API would not capture.

There could be `myNode.setWeight(double d)` and `myNode.getWeight()` methods, but they still don't define an iteration order in a way that's any better than you just adding a `weight` entry to your hashMap or `weight` field on your object.  Also, there might be different weights for bicycle routes or public transit, or whatever.  Would you have a set or hash of weights for every node?  I guess I don't see the use of a generic graph data structure because only the non-generic aspects of your data can make a graph traversable in anything close to polynomial time.

Comment: I would actually argue that your average programmer (and I include myself in this, hence my attempt to improve my knowledge of graphs) would be far more likely to design an overly complex class hierarchy to solve an issue that could be more easily tackled as a generic graph problem than vice versa. I also think that Boost graph proves that it is possible to provide an STL-like generic implementation that provides both graph and algorithm abstractions so I am honestly surprised that it isn't a more common feature in libraries.

Answer (score 1):

SWI Prolog includes [support for W3C RDF](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=semweb-rdf11), which is based on a graph data model (RDF triples can be considered to be a `vertex-edge-vertex` representation of graphs, a form of an adjacency list). There is support for transactions and on-disk storage. RDF seems to be the only model and a set of formats for storing and exchanging graph data that is in (relatively) common use today.